# MySQL Order By does not work for all records

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I run this query and need results to be sorted by status field.

```
SELECT status
FROM myusers
WHERE status IN (7,8,35)  
ORDER BY status DESC
```

I get response:

```
8
7
7
7
35
```

why it does not sort properly when i use `IN (7,8,35)`

Comment: checkmy answer below for my solution:)

Answer (score 2):

It's because your current column is in `string` format stored as `VARCHAR`. Cast it to integer to achieve correct result.

```
SELECT status
FROM myusers
WHERE status IN (7,8,35)  
ORDER BY CAST(status AS SIGNED) DESC
```

Or another way is to change the current data type of your `status` column to `INT`

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40b7f/3)

Answer (score 1):

Your `status` field should be a numerical field to be ordered correctly. The current order is clearly alphabetical.

Comment: Wow you right. I did not notice that it was varchar. However how is it CLEARLY alphabetical though i did not get how you saw it?

Comment: Alphabetical means it won't order by number. But char by char. 3 is before 7, so it considered a smaller value.

Answer (score 0):

Your status column is probably `VARCHAR`, convert it to an `INT` column and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your 'status' is of type VARCHAR, so the sort order is correct.
You're sorting descending, so "8" is (lexicographically) larger than "7" which is larger than "35".

For a numeric sort, change the datatype of the status field to a numeric one.

And for the order (7,8,35) you should use ORDER BY status ASC ;-)